# Get response from node.js server and call another method if condition is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a small node.js server with some simple routes.
From an index.html page I am doing a call using ajax to get data from the server.

First, when I open the website it verifies if the user is logged, if not I redirect the user to the route /login.

At the login the user gets authenticated, all ok and I redirect the user to another route where another call happens and it returns a json object.

My goal was to, through my website receive the response after the login was done, on the ajax request, not be redirected by the server and see the response.

```
function login()
{
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: '/',
      crossDomain : true,

  })
      .done(function( data ) {
          //window.location.replace('/me/notes')
          console.log("data received", data)
          if(xhr.status == 200)
          {
            getNotes();
          }
      })
      .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location.replace('/login')
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(textStatus);
      });
}

function getNotes()
{
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/me/notes',
  })
      .done(function( data ) {
          console.log("data", data)
          if(data)
          {
            document.write("data")
          }
      })
      .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location.replace('/login')
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(textStatus);
      });
}
```

I never really get to the point where I check `if(data == "ok")`

```
app.get('/auth', function(req, res){

      var token = request.exchangeAuthCodeForAccessToken()
      .then(function(token){
        console.log("token after login", req.session.token)

              res.send(res.status.code);

             //res.redirect('/me/notes');Here is where my problem happens
            //I tried: res.send("oK") but this gets executes instead of
            //triggering the if statement I want to check before calling another method

      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      })

});
```

My HTML header

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

How could I return the response from the server to my ajax request?

*ERROR*

The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that I created a webroute

```
app.get('/web/app', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + ("/index.html")));
   });
```

And then through the `index.html` I am verifying the login

```
function login()
{
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: '/',
      crossDomain : true,

  })
      .done(function( data ) {
          console.log("data", data)
          })
      .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location.replace('/login')
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(textStatus);
      });
}

login();
```